# OwnCloud How to set limit for a number of file upload to OwnCloud at a time

Tags: networking, cloud, upload, owncloud

Dont Know if this is the right place to post the question but i'm stuck here , need help

I'm having a problem that how can i set a limit number for quality of file upload to OwnCloud at a time ?
I means i'm the admin and i want to set an limit for user , they can only upload 3 file at a time in OwnCloud
I'm using window server 2008

Sorry for my English , it's just my secondary .

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can change `max_file_uploads` in your PHP and set it to 3.

Comment: i dont see the line max_file_uploads in PHP.ini and i added it but nothing happen
I'm using owncloud on window server 2008

Comment: @DuyĐặng what version of PHP are you using? In version 5.3.1 the support for max_file_uploads was added. See here: http://windows.php.net/

Comment: It's 5.4.3 , do you have any mail or something that i can contact you , i can send you a picture about my php , and does PHP.ini located at wamp/bin/php/php.5.4.3/php.ini ?